# Could gravity be the 4th dimension?

Tags: gravity

According to Michio Kaku, in his book Hyperspace, he said that in this Hyperspace, there exist a total of 10 dimensions that govern the laws of physics. Is it possible that we too live in a Hyperspace, and if so, would gravity be the 4th dimension that would govern the laws of physics we are yet to discover?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Dimensions are dimensions. Gravity is a force. Dimensions don't govern anything. We do live in the Universe, so if correct we live in a 10 dimensional universe....

Comment: Agree with @JamesKilfiger.  This isn't even really a question.  It's worded as a question, but asking if gravity is a dimension makes about as much sense as asking if gravity is time.   It's not hard to see that the properties of dimensions (space to move around in) is a different property than gravity.   Time is like a dimension, but in only one direction.  Gravity is nothing like a dimension and the 10 dimensions Michio Kaku was talking about, that's something else, only for the very small. And asking "laws of physics yet to be discovered", your question is all over the map.

Comment: X,Y,Z,t: spacetime.

Comment: This just makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

In [some models of quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) there are [10 dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory#Extra_dimensions). 7 of these are curled up and very small.

[Gravity](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14148/how-does-gravity-really-work?rq=1) is a force it is not a dimension.

If these models of quantum gravity is correct then we do live in these 10 dimension. If these models are correct then we do live in "hyperspace", but only 3 dimensions are macroscopic.

Dimensions don't govern the laws of physics.

Comment: Gravity is not even a force, though.